# How to remove the "Path" line in the WordPress Editor for end users who are submitting a form?

Tags: wp-editor

There is a horizontal box of one-line height at the bottom with the character "p" in it that I want to get rid of for end users.  I don't really care if it is there in the Dashboard Editor for site admins/editors.  This line seems to indicate the formatting of the line where the cursor is.   End users are providing feedback "so, what's the p?".  Can we remove that box?

Answer (score 1):

This is how the tinymce statusbar displays on my intsall:

```
<div id="mceu_34" class="mce-statusbar mce-container mce-panel mce-stack-layout-item mce-last" hidefocus="1" tabindex="-1" role="group">
    <div id="mceu_34-body" class="mce-container-body mce-flow-layout">
        <div id="mceu_35" class="mce-path mce-flow-layout-item mce-first mce-last">
            <div role="button" class="mce-path-item" data-index="0" tabindex="-1" id="mceu_35-0" aria-level="0">p</div>
            <div class="mce-divider" aria-hidden="true"> » </div>
            <div role="button" class="mce-path-item mce-last" data-index="1" tabindex="-1" id="mceu_35-1" aria-level="1">strong</div>   
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

so this suggests hiding it with CSS.

You probably want to keep the statusbar visible but hide the `div.mce-path`.

The `tiny_mce_before_init` hook might come useful to target the tinymce editor:

```
add_filter( 'tiny_mce_before_init', function( $settings )
{
    ?><style>.mce-path{display:none;}</style><?php
    return $settings;
} );
```

But there must be a native way, so I simply searched for the *mce-path* keyword and this question on StackOverflow popped up first:

[Remove path in status bar in TinyMCE4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17193624/remove-path-in-status-bar-in-tinymce4)

There it's suggested by @BeckJohnson to use:

```
tinymce.init({ elementpath: false });
```

so we can try that with:

```
add_filter( 'tiny_mce_before_init', function( $settings )
{
    $settings['elementpath'] = false;
    return $settings;   
});
```

and that seems to do the trick.

Comment: you're welcome, glad to hear it worked for you @BJBrowning

Answer (score 0):

It's called the Element Path located in the editor's status bar.

You remove it by setting its *tinymce.init* setting of *elementpath* to false.

```
{'elementpath': false}
```

In Wordpress, that setting can be altered in the `tiny_mce_before_init` filter.

```
add_filter('tiny_mce_before_init', function ($init) {
$init['elementpath'] = false;
return $init; });
```

Make sure you add the filter before you invoke the editor function or it will not take effect.

Comment: Thank you as well Scriptonomy - this seems to be the code snippet required!

Answer (score 0):

It shows what HTML tags are open.

Just tell them what it is and add "if you don't know what that means, just ignore it. It is nothing you need to worry about."

Why go making code changes when they are not needed?

Comment: because UX is important. In general I agree with you, but if the user cares then it should be fixed. Usually it is faster than trying to educate the user.

Comment: "IT" is not broken so "IT" can't be fixed. As I said, it is a there as an editing/authoring aid.Why not remove the formatting bar, the Add Media link, the word count at the bottom of the editing area, and or the text mode? As to "UX" I assume you mean user experience. I cannot see how encountering something that they don't understand but does not obviously cause any problem for them can't simply be explained as an editing aid that they will likely never need to be concerned with.  What is the URL of your site, I'd like to see how the UX is on it. -  I stand my my original statement.

Comment: Thanks so much for your comments to my question.  Our website is still in beta and undergoing redesign, so I don't want to divulge the URL just yet - but it will be awesome!  Our end user community will appreciate the online form being really simple; the more streamlined, the more appealing.